# Display localised price in-app with Stripe

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I want to set up a multiparty payment system within my app where someone creates an "event", sets the price for tickets for it, and then gets paid for those sales, minus my platform's fee.

I plan on using Stripe for this. However, users can be in different countries and should be able to see the price of the ticket in their own currency. As far as I'm aware, Stripe converts the currency in the payment checkout. However, I need to display that price within my app before the user gets there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Stripe doesn’t automatically convert currency at checkout. If you want to support multiple currencies for your product, then you can create multiple prices in different currencies for the product and pick the right price to use based on the user’s locale.

Beyond that, if price conversion at checkout is something that’d be useful for you, it might even be worth it to contact Stripe’s support to let them know.

Comment: Ah I thought it did. Okay thanks for that info... I don't actually have a product, it would be an amount that the user who sets up the event will define. So you're saying actually there should be multiple "products" with specific prices that they can select. E.g. Ticket 1 - £9.99, Ticket 2 - £15.99, etc. And then Ticket 2 could have an equivalent price in euros?

Comment: @Tometoyou I guess that would depend on your use-case. Assuming you do have a set of products, yes, that pattern of creating products with associated prices in Euros, USD, CAD, etc. that you outlined is the way to go. Alternatively you can do ad-hoc prices: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#ad-hoc-prices.